# Are there any utilities out there that allow you to manually define available screen area?

Tags: display, screen, gpu

I have a spare 27 inch monitor that I'd like to use in vertical mode as a side monitor, but it's way too tall - are there any tools out there that allow you to manually define the effective usable area of the display (as if the screen was actually a different size)?

I'm guessing this would have to be done by the GPU, if it's even possible?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm after:

[image]

Comment: See [this Meta answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a hardware/software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.